# How to use Jquery fadeOut when hiding a div

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I want when a div is hidden, to have a fadeOut effect for a smooth effect.

I've tried many ways but every time it gives me a mistake and I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="onboarding" id="onboarding">
<div class="onboarding-content"></div>
<div class="finish-btn customNavigation" id="finish-btn">
  <button type="button" name="button">
     <a class="btn next">
        <svg width="20" height="14" viewBox="0 0 20 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M19 1L7 13L1 7" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if ($.cookie('hide-div')) {
    $("#onboarding").remove();
}

$(".finish-btn").click(function() {
    $("#onboarding").remove();
    $.cookie('hide-div', true);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you implement the jQuery `.fadeOut()` method - note the use of a callback to remove the div after the fadeOut finishes.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$(".finish-btn").click(function() {
    $("#onboarding").fadeOut(700, function(){
       $("#onboarding").remove();
       //$.cookie('hide-div', true);
    });
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="onboarding">Onboarding DIV</div>
<button class="finish-btn">Hide Div</button>
```